# Imputing the missing values string using a condition(pandas DataFrame)

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

Kaggle Dataset(working on)- Newyork Airbnb

Created with a raw data code for running better explanation of the issue

```
`airbnb= pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rafagarciac/Airbnb_NYC-Data-Science_Project/master/input/new-york-city-airbnb-open-data/AB_NYC_2019.csv")

airbnb[airbnb["host_name"].isnull()][["host_name","neighbourhood_group"]]
```

`[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfyXT.png)

I would like to fill the null values of "host_name" based on the "neighbourhood_group" column entities. 
like

```
if airbnb['host_name'].isnull():
   airbnb["neighbourhood_group"]=="Bronx"
   airbnb["host_name"]= "Vie"

elif:
        airbnb["neighbourhood_group"]=="Manhattan"
        airbnb["host_name"]= "Sonder (NYC)"
    else:
        airbnb["host_name"]= "Michael"
```

(this is wrong,just to represent the output format i want)

I've tried using if statement but I couldn't apply in a correct way. Could you please me solve this.

Thanks

Comment: Kindly avoid posting snapshots of the data frame, rather define a sample of it in your code using `airbnb = pd.DataFrame(data)`, this makes it easy for us to run your code and suggest a solution.

Comment: @ Cavin Dsouza thanks for suggestion. Its on one of the data-set to practice on kaggle" Newyork Airbnb" as a part of data cleaning(filling missing values). "https://www.kaggle.com/dgomonov/new-york-city-airbnb-open-data" - I don't know to express rather than presenting the problem with snapshot to be specific. Could you guide me through. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this -

```
airbnb.loc[(airbnb['host_name'].isnull()) & (airbnb["neighbourhood_group"]=="Bronx"), "host_name"] = "Vie"
airbnb.loc[(airbnb['host_name'].isnull()) & (airbnb["neighbourhood_group"]=="Manhattan"), "host_name"] = "Sonder (NYC)"
airbnb.loc[airbnb['host_name'].isnull(), "host_name"] = "Michael"
```

Comment: @ Cavin Dsouza Wow, great thanks a lot. It worked like a cake :)

Comment: could you please explain how the host_name inside the loc after the  conditions work ( this part---> "Bronx" ), "host_name"] = "Vie")

Comment: Sure, the syntax for `.loc` is as follows: `df.loc[(some_condition), [list_of_columns to update]) = modified_value`, so then for eg:, this line ```airbnb.loc[(airbnb['host_name'].isnull()) & (airbnb["neighbourhood_group"]=="Bronx"), "host_name"] = "Vie"``` translates to - assign `host_name` to `Vie` if `host_name` is null and `neighbourhood_group` is `Bronx`

Comment: Understood perfect. Thanks again :)

Comment: @ desertnaut thanks for educating me :), Do I need to earn 15 points to mark as answered because I couldn't find the option near the answer tab. Kindly let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas has a special method to fill NA values:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

You may create a dict with values for "host_name" field using "neighbourhood_group" values as keys and do this:

```
host_dict = {'Bronx': 'Vie', 'Manhattan': 'Sonder (NYC)'}     
airbnb['host_name'] = airbnb['host_name'].fillna(value=airbnb[airbnb['host_name'].isna()]['neighbourhood_group'].map(host_dict))
airbnb['host_name'] = airbnb['host_name'].fillna("Michael")
```

"value" argument here may be a [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) of values.

So, first of all, we create a Series with "neighbourhood_group" values which correspond to our missing values by using this part:

```
neighbourhood_group_series = airbnb[airbnb['host_name'].isna()]['neighbourhood_group']
```

Then using [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) function together with "host_dict" we get a Series with values that we want to impute:

```
neighbourhood_group_series.map(host_dict)
```

Finally we just impute in all other NA cells some default value, in our case "Michael".

Comment: thanks Ivan, it looked complicated but your explanation made it crystal clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with:

```py
ornek = pd.DataFrame({'samp1': [None, None, None],
                     'samp2': ["sezer", "bozkir", "farkli"]})

def filter_by_col(row):
    if row["samp2"] == "sezer":
        return "ping"
    if row["samp2"] == "bozkir":
        return "pong"
    return None

ornek.apply(lambda x: filter_by_col(x), axis=1)
```

Comment: I tried your code ,couldn't get the changes after applying, did i miss something!